# How to make a banner take up the whole width of the screen CSS

Tags: html, css

i need the div bar to take up the whole width of the screen. I've tried using width:1920px; but then if i change my screen res it gives it a scroll bar. I've also tried width:100%; but that didn't work either!

CSS

```css
#bar {
    background: white;
    font-family: Designio;
    margin-top: -76px;
    position: absoulte;
    top: 115px;
    padding: 15px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 1930px;
    margin-left: -600px;
    background-size: 100%;
}

body {
    min-width: 768px;
    margin: 0px;
    background: #0e6585;
    font-size: 40px;
}

img.top {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#container {
    height: 768px;
    background: #0e6585;
    font-family: Designio
}

#inner {
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 10px 2px #fff;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    background: #0e6585;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #946e44;
    text-align: center;
}

#nav a.active {
    background-color: #0e6586;
    color: white;
}

#nav {
    height: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-top: -10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

#nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center
}

#nav li {
    float: left;
    text-align: center
}

#nav li a {
    margin-top: 15px;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0e6585;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    text-align: center
}

#nav li a:hover {
    color: #0e6586;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center
}
```

HTML

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Primary.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">

            <div id="inner">

                <div style="margin-top: -120px">

                    <div id ="bar">
                        <div id="nav">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="home.html" class="active">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">About</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Graphics</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Web Design</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get an element to fill the width of the viewport, it should either be absolutely positioned, and a descendant only of elements which also fill the width of the viewport (eg: `body`, descendant divs of `body` which do not have set widths), OR it should be fixed position. Then, the element needs to have `left: 0` and `right: 0`.

Change your `#bar` ruleset to this:

```css
#bar{
    background:white;
    font-family:Designio;
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding:15px;
    height:60px;
    background-size:100%;      
}
```

summary:

1. Remove all redundant sizing and negative margin properties.
2. Fix the typo in your stylesheet - change `position: absoulte` to `position: absolute`.
3. Set `left: 0` and `right: 0`.

demo: http://jsbin.com/ofeful/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

Use margin on your parent div.

```
.container
{
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

A fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PVKbp/

In another blaring omission of reading, your `#bar` element is set to position absolutely within two other elements. You'll need to take it out of the the container (unless you need it positioned within the container) in order for `left: 0; right: 0` to work properly. If you need it to be within the container, you'll also need to extend the container using the margin properties above.

Comment: Parent div? What do you mean?

Comment: In your case the `container` div. I'll edit to reflect that. I didn't even look at your class names honestly.

Comment: I am very confused. The answer works, unless `display:inline` is specified. Why is  that? Thought `display:inline` pertains only to the children, not to the element itself?

Comment: @ТаняТ.: No, the selector applies directly on the element to which it's applied. The children are only affected by the manner in which the selector affects the element itself.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `width:*;`. That should make it take up the whole screen in width.